# Code for app that constantly generates network traffic

Tags: java, android, traffic

I need help with a code that would enable app to constantly generate some small amount of network traffic and then stop for a couple of seconds and then again repeat procedure. I need this app for testing because I'm building another app that would monitor it.

I am beginner in Android development so I'm really not sure how to start. It doesn't matter what will this app do and where will send data or receive. It just needs to generate some traffic constantly. I you understand what I mean :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a WebView and periodically retrieve a webpage.